# How do I make JSON.stringify work on a NativeJavaArray?

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, json, rhino

I have a script that runs on the NetSuite platform, which I'm 99% sure is using the Rhino JavaScript engine. I'm trying to get the same script to work locally, but there's a problem with calling `JSON.stringify` on a wrapped Java array. In both environments, the array is of type `[object JavaArray]`, but while the Java array is properly stringified on NetSuite, my local Rhino context says:

> org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Java class "[Ljava.lang.String;" has no public instance field or method named "toJSON".

At first I thought they had augmented the `NativeJavaArray` class with a `toJSON` method and returned it through a custom `WrapFactory`, but that doesn't appear to be the case as there's no `toJSON` method on the returned object.

Is there an option that I need to tweak to make Java arrays work with the JSON methods? I should be able to work around it by adding `toJSON` to a subclass of `NativeJavaArray` as I mentioned above, but I would like to be as compatible with NetSuite's environment as possible.

Comment: You need to use JsonArray

Comment: Can you be more specific? Rhino doesn't have a JsonArray class, as far as I can tell. I'm simply returning a `String[]` from a bound Java method and Rhino automatically wraps it with NativeJavaArray.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html